# How to preserve navigation stack when navigating to another route with context.go() - GoRouter

Tags: flutter, flutter-go-router

When you navigate with `context.go()`, if the target route is a sub-route of the existing route, it adds the target route on top of the existing route, which preserves the navigation stack. But if it is not a sub-route (/another-route), the existing route is replaced with the target route.

`context.push()` can be used to navigate to the target route (/another-route), doing this will preserve the navigation stack, but doing so no longer changes the URL on web.

My question; how do I navigate to a different route with `context.go()` and preserve the navigation stack?

Although with context.push(), I can use:

`GoRouter.optionURLReflectsImperativeAPIs = true;`

which will ensure the URL changes

It is my understanding though that context.push() is an imperative API, and so I would prefer to not use it.

```
final _rootNavigation = GlobalKey<NavigatorState>(debugLabel: 'root');
final route = GoRouter(
  initialLocation: '/signup',
  navigatorKey: _rootNavigation,
  routes: [
    GoRoute(
      parentNavigatorKey: _rootNavigation,
      path: '/signup',
      builder: (context, state) => const SignUpScreen(),
    ),
    GoRoute(
      parentNavigatorKey: _rootNavigation,
      path: '/signin',
      builder: (context, state) => const SignInScreen(),
    ),
  ],
);
```

If I navigate from `/signup` to `/signin` with `context.go('/signin')`, SignUpScreen is replaced with SignInScreen.

---

Or, is my route configuration wrong and so I should never have to find myself in this situation?

```
final route = GoRouter(
  initialLocation: '/auth',
  navigatorKey: _rootNavigation,
  routes: [
    GoRoute(
      parentNavigatorKey: _rootNavigation,
      path: '/auth',
      redirect: (_, __) => '/auth/signup',
      routes: [
        GoRoute(
          parentNavigatorKey: _rootNavigation,
          path: 'signup',
          builder: (context, state) => const SignUpScreen(),
        ),
        GoRoute(
          parentNavigatorKey: _rootNavigation,
          path: 'signin',
          builder: (context, state) => const SignInScreen(),
        ),
      ],
    ),
  ],
);
```

Is the above what I am meant to do? If so, in a situation where I have a BottomNavigationBar and I'm using either the `ShellRoute` or `StatefulShellRoute`, how does this apply when navigating to a route that is not a child of any of the shell routes?

My issue has nothing to do with flutter web but rather that `contex.push()` is an imperative API.

Comment: It's very unclear from the `go_router` docs whether we should use the `Imperative APIs` or not, and how to implement an `Imperative` kind of navigation stack with only `context.go()`

Answer (score 2):

I'm not an expert with navigator keys, but I think the way you are using them might be incorrect. I would remove those, and turn on the GoRouter debugLogDiagnostics to watch your navigator in action.

EG:

```
    import 'package:go_router/go_router.dart';

import 'src/src.dart';

enum AppPages {
  home,
  builder,
}

GoRouter routerConfig = GoRouter(
  initialLocation: '/',
  debugLogDiagnostics: true,
  routes: [
    GoRoute(
      path: '/',
      name: AppPages.home.name,
      builder: (context, state) => const HomePage(),
      routes: <GoRoute>[
        GoRoute(
          path: 'builder',
          name: AppPages.builder.name,
          builder: (context, state) => const BuilderPage(),
        ),
      ],
    ),
  ],
);
```

If you are creating an auth flow where you have a `LoginPage`, `SignUpPage`, and a 'ForgotPasswordPage` you could set them up like this:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
// ignore:depend_on_referenced_packages
import 'package:flutter_web_plugins/url_strategy.dart';
import 'package:go_router/go_router.dart';

void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

  // Removes the '#' from the URLs in web applications.
  usePathUrlStrategy();

  runApp(const App());
}

class App extends StatelessWidget {
  const App({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp.router(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: 'Text Crawler',
      theme: ThemeData(
        colorScheme: ColorScheme.fromSeed(
          seedColor: Colors.amberAccent,
        ),
      ),
      routerConfig: routerConfig,
    );
  }
}

enum AppPages {
  home,
  login,
  signUp,
  forgotPassword,
}

GoRouter routerConfig = GoRouter(
  initialLocation: '/',
  debugLogDiagnostics: true,
  routes: [
    GoRoute(
      path: '/',
      name: AppPages.home.name,
      builder: (context, state) => const HomePage(),
      routes: <GoRoute>[
        GoRoute(
          // child route of '/'
          path: 'login',
          name: AppPages.login.name,
          builder: (context, state) => const LoginPage(),
        ),
        GoRoute(
          // child route of '/'
          path: 'signUp',
          name: AppPages.signUp.name,
          builder: (context, state) => const SignUpPage(),
        ),
        GoRoute(
          // child route of '/'
          path: 'forgotPassword',
          name: AppPages.forgotPassword.name,
          builder: (context, state) => const ForgotPasswordPage(),
        ),
      ],
    ),
  ],
);

class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  const HomePage({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Home Page'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            FilledButton(
              onPressed: () {
                // Push page onto the stack
                GoRouter.of(context).pushNamed(AppPages.login.name);
              },
              child: const Text(
                'Push Sign In Page',
              ),
            ),
            const SizedBox(
              height: 8,
            ),
            FilledButton(
              onPressed: () {
                // Push replacment page onto the stack
                // You cannot use .pop() because the entire stack has been replaced.
                GoRouter.of(context).pushReplacementNamed(AppPages.login.name);
              },
              child: const Text(
                'Push replacement Sign In Page',
              ),
            ),
            const SizedBox(
              height: 8,
            ),
            TextButton(
              onPressed: () {
                // Push page onto the stack
                GoRouter.of(context).pop();
              },
              child: const Text(
                'Pop this page from the navigator stack',
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class LoginPage extends StatelessWidget {
  const LoginPage({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Login Page'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            FilledButton(
              onPressed: () {
                // Push page onto the stack
                GoRouter.of(context).pushNamed(AppPages.signUp.name);
              },
              child: const Text(
                'Push Sign Up Page',
              ),
            ),
            const SizedBox(
              height: 8,
            ),
            FilledButton(
              onPressed: () {
                // Push page onto the stack
                GoRouter.of(context).pushNamed(AppPages.forgotPassword.name);
              },
              child: const Text(
                'Push Forgot password page',
              ),
            ),
            const SizedBox(
              height: 8,
            ),
            TextButton(
              onPressed: () {
                // Push page onto the stack
                GoRouter.of(context).pop();
              },
              child: const Text(
                'Pop this page from the navigator stack',
              ),
            ),
            const SizedBox(
              height: 8,
            ),
            ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () {
                // Push the original home page onto the stack and remove all other pages
                GoRouter.of(context).pushReplacementNamed(AppPages.home.name);
              },
              child: const Text(
                'Push the original home page onto the stack and remove all other pages',
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class ForgotPasswordPage extends StatelessWidget {
  const ForgotPasswordPage({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Forgot Password Page'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            TextButton(
              onPressed: () {
                // Push page onto the stack
                GoRouter.of(context).pop();
              },
              child: const Text(
                'Pop this page from the navigator stack',
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class SignUpPage extends StatelessWidget {
  const SignUpPage({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Sign up Page'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            TextButton(
              onPressed: () {
                // Push page onto the stack
                GoRouter.of(context).pop();
              },
              child: const Text(
                'Pop this page from the navigator stack',
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I'm not sure if this answers your question or not. Here is the example on dartpad.dev:

https://dartpad.dev/?id=4816ec3af7298a33d533f1cfc0a85b04

Comment: I appreciate your response. There are some things I can point out from your example, but i will just mention what's more important now.

From the example you gave. You have one root route whose path is `'/'`, should all my routes be under one root route? Probably not. 

If I have another root route `GoRoute(path: '/something-else')`, navigating from `'/'` to `'/somethin-else'` with `context.go` will replace the existing route with the target; this is were my issue is. But with context.push or .pushNamed, both routes are preserved, but it is an imperative api